# How to start/stop React Native Moti animation on state change? My way seems to break the animation for some reason

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, moti

I am trying the following Moti animation which works fine until I add the `playbackState === State.Playing`. Once I add it, it only loops once and then gets stuck/stops repeating. I'm wondering if anyone has any clue why this might be happening.

```
{playbackState === State.Playing &&
[...Array(3).keys()].map((index) => {
    return (
        <SoundWave
            top={height * 0.365}
            from={{ opacity: 1, scale: 1 }}
            animate={{ opacity: 0, scale: 2 }}
            transition={{
                type: 'timing',
                duration: 4400,
                easing: Easing.out(Easing.ease),
                delay: index * 1400,
                repeatReverse: false,
                loop: true,
            }}
            key={index}
        />
    );
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

what i did was enabling disabling the animate and transition props

```
<MotiView
        from={{
          opacity: 0.7,
          scale: 1,
        }}
        animate={isPlaying ? {
          opacity: 0,
          scale: 1.2,
        } : {
          opacity: 0.7,
          scale: 1,
        }}
        transition={isPlaying ? 
          {
            type: 'timing',
            duration: exercise.duration,
            easing: Easing.out(Easing.ease),
            delay: exercise.delayDuration,
            repeatReverse: exercise.reverse, // stop moving bakwards
            loop: true,
          }:{}}
      >
```